# How to write the path locally to the MathJax library in ckeditor?

Tags: math, ckeditor, formula, mathjax

Good morning all.

I am currently developing a small local app that integrates the editor ckeditor. I downloaded a plugin of mathematical characters which runs with MathJax. The problem is that online everything is going well, but the offline configuration just messes up.

For online configuration, the code in the MathJax ckeditor file is as follows:
`config.mathJaxLib = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';`

Now I would also like to work offline. Which led me to change the config which is:`config.mathJaxLib = 'var/www/html/infoFacile/js/MathJax/MathJax.js';` in absolute
or 
`config.mathJaxLib = '../MathJax/MathJax.js';`

With this local config, the plugin no longer displays mathematical characters. We are well faced with a path problem (I think), but I don't know how to get out of it.

Anyone have an idea? thank you

Comment: Do you have a full installation of MathJax (which is much more than MathJax.js) at the location? Also, you have dropped the configuration part from the query string so it's unclear how you configure MathJax.

Comment: Hello Peter, what part of the configuration did I delete? Regarding the full version yes I downloaded it entirely. I put it in a MathJax folder with all of its subdirectories and files. How can I process now ?

Comment: I added the queryString without much change:
config.mathJaxLib = 'http: //localhost/infoFacile/js/MathJax/MathJax.js? config = TeX-AMS_HTML';

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console that would give you a hint?

Comment: My problem is solved. I have deleted all MathJax files from ckeditor. I downloaded the current version in github. I created a MathJax folder in my big var/www/html folder and I simply configured my config.js file from ckeditor like this:
config.mathJaxLib = 'http: //localhost/MathJax/MathJax.js? config = TeX-AMS_HTML'; Thank you Peter

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.